# What is the difference between inline-block and inline-table?

Tags: html, css

As far as I can tell, these `display` selectors seem to be identical.

From the Mozilla CSS documentation:

`inline-table`: The inline-table value does not have a direct mapping in HTML. It behaves like a `<table>` HTML element, but as an inline box, rather than a block-level box. Inside the table box is a block-level context.

`inline-block`: The element generates a block element box that will be flowed with surrounding content as if it were a single inline box (behaving much like a replaced element would).

It seems that whatever could be done with `inline-table` can be done with `inline-block`.

Comment: `display: inline-table` is not just for non-table elements.  Sometimes you want tables to be inline, too.

Comment: "It seems that whatever could be done with `inline-table` can be done with `inline-block`." I don't think this is true, because there are some differences between table elements and block elements (particularly with regard to how child elements are handled). See https://stackoverflow.com/q/25048236 for more detail about that.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`display:table` will make your tag behave like a table.
`inline-table` just means that the element is displayed as an inline-level table. You can then do `table-cell` to let your element behave like a `<td>` element.

`display:inline` - displays your element as an inline element (like `<span>`), and `inline-block` will just group them together in a block container.

As the other answer suggested you can replace between the two as long as you follow the display convention in the rest of your code. (i.e. use `table-cell` with `inline-table` and not with `inline-block`).
Check [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) for more info on `display`.

Comment: should we set all span to inline-table inside a table? (i found this useful for any "float" on these span)

Answer (score 91):

Both [`inline-block`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-inline-block) and [`inline-table`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-inline-table) have an [`inline`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-inline) [outer display role](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#outer-role). That means

> The element generates an *inline-level box*.

The difference is that

- [`inline-block`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-inline-block) has a [`flow-root`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-flow-root) [inner display model](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#inner-model), that is

  > The element generates a [block container](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#block-container) box, and lays out its
  >   contents using [flow layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#flow-layout). It always establishes a new [block
  >   formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#block-formatting-context) for its contents.
- [`inline-table`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-inline-table) has a [`table`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-table) [inner display model](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#inner-model), that is

  > The element generates a principal *table wrapper box* containing an
  >   additionally-generated *table box*, and establishes a *table
  >   formatting context*.

However, in most cases, `inline-table` will behave like `inline-block` because of [anonymous table objects](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#anonymous-boxes):

> Generate missing child wrappers:
>
> - If a child C of a 'table' or 'inline-table' box is not a proper table child, then generate an anonymous 'table-row' box around C and
>     all consecutive siblings of C that are not proper table children.
> - If a child C of a 'table-row' box is not a 'table-cell', then generate an anonymous 'table-cell' box around C and all consecutive
>     siblings of C that are not 'table-cell' boxes.

Therefore, if your `inline-table` element has non-tabular content, that content will be wrapped in an anonymous `table-cell`.

And [`table-cell`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-table-cell) has a [`flow-root`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-flow-root) [inner display model](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#inner-model), just like `inline-block`.

But if the `inline-table` has tabular content, it will behave differently than `inline-block`.

Some examples:

- Inside an `inline-block`, cells with non-tabular separator will generate different `table` anonymous parents, so they will appear at different lines. Inside an `inline-table`, it will be the separator who will generate a `table-cell` parent, so they all will appear at the same row.

  ```css
  .itable {
    display: inline-table;
  }
  .iblock {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .cell {
    display: table-cell;
  }
  .wrapper > span {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <fieldset>
    <legend>inline-table</legend>
    <div class="itable wrapper">
      <span class="cell">table-cell</span>
      <span class="iblock">inline-block</span>
      <span class="cell">table-cell</span>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>inline-block</legend>
    <div class="iblock wrapper">
      <span class="cell">table-cell</span>
      <span class="iblock">inline-block</span>
      <span class="cell">table-cell</span>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  ```
- Inner cells won't grow to fill a wide `inline-block`:

  ```css
  .itable {
    display: inline-table;
  }
  .iblock {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .cell {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <fieldset>
    <legend>inline-table</legend>
    <div class="itable wrapper">
      <span class="cell">table-cell</span>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>inline-block</legend>
    <div class="iblock wrapper">
      <span class="cell">table-cell</span>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  ```
- The border of the `inline-block` won't collapse with the border of the inner cells:

  ```css
  .wrapper, .cell {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 5px solid #000;
  }
  .itable {
    display: inline-table;
  }
  .iblock {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .cell {
    display: table-cell;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <fieldset>
    <legend>inline-table</legend>
    <div class="itable wrapper">
      <span class="cell">table-cell</span>
      <span class="cell">table-cell</span>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>inline-block</legend>
    <div class="iblock wrapper">
      <span class="cell">table-cell</span>
      <span class="cell">table-cell</span>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  ```

Comment: Glad to see the spec sorted that out

Comment: @TylerH Yes, CSS Display said `flow`, but CSS 2.1 said table-cells always establish a formatting context. I never understood why they didn't say the inner display model was `flow-root` from the very beginning. I even emailed the CSS WG but they ignored me.

Comment: I find that shameless pinging of spec authors on Twitter is effective. It's worked for me a few times, now. :-)

Comment: @Oriol one thing I don't understand, you said that _If a child C of a 'table-row' box is not a 'table-cell', then generate an anonymous 'table-cell' box around C and all consecutive siblings of C that are not 'table-cell' boxes_. but if inside a `display: table-row` element I have a few elements with `display: block` they don't behave as table-cell. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

Here are relevant differences in practice. Run the code snippet to see it at first glance.

- **Vertical alignment of surrounding text**:
   `inline-table` elements align with its top cell or top baseline (if content is only multiple lines of text). 
  Text around `inline-box` aligns with its bottom.
- `height` works different, e.g. `height`is probably not as you expect on 
  `<table style=display:inline-block>` (see **test5** and **6**)
- `width` and overflow works different, 
  e.g. setting width smaller than content, see **test7, 8, 9, 10**

```html
<style>
     table, span { background:gold; color:red }
     th, td { background:silver }
</style>

_test1
     <span style=display:inline-block> 
       display <br> inline <br> block
     </span>
_test2
     <span style=display:inline-table>
       display <br> inline <br> table
     </span>
_test3
     <table style=display:inline-block>
       <tr><th> inline
       <tr><td> block
     </table>
_test4
     <table style=display:inline-table>
       <tr><th> inline
       <tr><td> table
     </table>
_test5
     <table style=display:inline-block;height:5em>
       <tr><th> inline
       <tr><td> block
     </table>
_test6
     <table style=display:inline-table;height:5em>
       <tr><th> inline
       <tr><td> table
     </table>_
<br>
_test7
     <span style=display:inline-block;width:1.4em>
       block
     </span>
_test8
     <span style=display:inline-table;width:1.4em>
       table
     </span>
_test9
     <table style=display:inline-block;width:1.4em>
       <tr><th> inline
       <tr><td> block
     </table>
_test10
     <table style=display:inline-table;width:1.4em>
       <tr><th> inline
       <tr><td> table
     </table>
_test11
     <table style=display:inline-block;width:5em>
       <tr><th> inline
       <tr><td> block
     </table>
_test12
     <table style=display:inline-table;width:5em>
       <tr><th> inline
       <tr><td> table
     </table>_
```

Comment: The examples make this a wonderful answer. Thanks.