# CSS: display:block; vs display:table;

Tags: html, css, html-table

Is there a difference between `display:block;` and `display:table;`? It looks to me like the display type of the dom-node containing `table-row` and `table-cell` nodes doesn't matter. [MDN says that `display:table;` makes it behave like a table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display), but doesn't elaborate on what that behavior is. What is that behavior?

Similarly, is there a difference between `display:inline-block;` and `display:inline-table;`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Comparing the two (block and table), I don't know of any core differences (there may be minor ones) you would see within a vacuum. I believe the major differences are specifically to children. Tables and their children have very different attributes/relationships than a div and its children.

As far as inline-block and inline-table see: [What is the difference between inline-block and inline-table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352072/what-is-the-difference-between-inline-block-and-inline-table)

This article (http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/) has some interesting information, specifically regarding all the different display properties related to a table.

Comment: One of the other answers makes it a lot more clear what it means to "behave like a table". A couple of the major differences I'm seeing is that elements with some children that are and some children that aren't table-rows, work differently depending on whether its display:table or display:block. Thanks!

Comment: -1 for overlooking the fact that `display: block` takes up 100% of available width, whereas `display: table` is only as wide as its contents require. That's not a minor difference: in many cases it completely changes the layout of the page.

Answer (score 14):

Both will be block-level, in that they won't display next to anything else, by default.

There is a significant difference in the actual display of the element. `display: block;` will extend to 100% of the available space, while `display: table;` will only be as wide as its contents.

Also, as others have mentioned, `display: table;` is required to get `display: table-cell;` or other `table-` stuff to work in the descendents.

I only know this because I just ran into the problem of trying to get the `display: table;` to fill the width of the container. I haven't been able to see if there is a difference in the display of `display: inline;` and `display: inline-table;`.

https://jsfiddle.net/nnbonhc6/

Comment: As someone else noted below, another difference is that `overflow: auto`/`overflow: scroll` does not work on tables. I wanted to have scrollbars without wrapping the `table` in a `div` (as my tables are coming from Markdown), though. Setting `table { display: block; overflow-x: auto; }` solved the scrolling but prevented me from horizontally centering tables that don't span the full width with `margin: 0 auto;` due to what you described. After some searching, I found that `max-width: [-webkit-|-moz-]fit-content` on the `display: block` table does the trick.

Answer (score 7):

I was researching this today, and I found this section of the CSS spec to be helpful: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#model

Notably,

> the table generates a principal block box called the table wrapper box
>   that contains the table box itself and any caption boxes (in document
>   order). The table box is a block-level box that contains the table's
>   internal table boxes.

As I understand it, this essentially means the browser generates an invisible container block for anything with `display: table`!

Comment: That's a good point! It will have obvious impact when table is used as a "flex" child: in that case its principal block box will be explicit!

Answer (score 7):

One difference that seems to exist is that `display:table` clears the line (as a `display:block` would) but does not expand to fill the line (a display block would take the maximum amount of width, an inline would not)

So you can get a box that resizes with your content, but stays alone in its "line"

Answer (score 4):

there is another difference i found between `display:block` and `display:table` in that when either have `position:fixed`, `top:0`, `left:0`, `right:0`, `bottom:0`, `overflow:auto`, if the content exceeds the viewport, `display:block` **will** show the scrollbar and `display:table` **will not**

Comment: Have you found a way to have the scrollbar and the full width of display table?

Comment: What do you mean with "the full width of display table", @HahnSolo? You get a table to span the full width with `width: 100%`. If, on the contrary, you want a block to be only as wide as its children (in order to center it horizontally with `margin: auto`), similar to the behavior of a table, you can use `max-width: fit-content` on the block. (Vendor prefixes seem to be necessary, so also `max-width: -webkit-fit-content` and `max-width: -moz-fit-content`, see [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_width_fit-content).)

Answer (score 3):

One major benefit of using `display: table` instead of `display: block` on a parent element is that you can safely use `display: inline-block` on the child elements, without having to worry about the white-space between the children.

Otherwise you'd have to get rid of that extra white-space by using html comments between the closing/opening tags (for example with multiple `<li>` elements for the typical horizontal nav), or putting everything in-line in your code without carrier returns (which is an editing nightmare).

Comment: This sounds like a hack/side-effect more than an intended use case.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I find another example for the difference between `display: block` and `display: table`

I take the email template from litmus:

```
<table class="row footer">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="wrapper">

        <table class="six columns">
          <tbody><tr>
            <td class="left-text-pad">

              <h5>Connect With Us:</h5>

              <table class="tiny-button facebook">
                <tbody><tr>
                  <td>
                    <a href="#">Facebook</a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody></table>

              <br>

              <table class="tiny-button twitter">
                <tbody><tr>
                  <td>
                    <a href="#">Twitter</a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody></table>

              <br>

              <table class="tiny-button google-plus">
                <tbody><tr>
                  <td>
                    <a href="#">Google +</a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody></table>

            </td>
            <td class="expander"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody></table>

      </td>
      <td class="wrapper last">

        <table class="six columns">
          <tbody><tr>
            <td class="last right-text-pad">
              <h5>Contact Info:</h5>
              <p>Phone: 408.341.0600</p>
              <p>Email: <a href="mailto:hseldon@trantor.com">hseldon@trantor.com</a></p>
            </td>
            <td class="expander"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody></table>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

with `display: block !important;` on footer table, It looks:

[image: display:block iOS 10 mail example]

with `display: table !important;` on footer table, It looks:

[image: display:table iOS 10 mail example]

The snapshot is take with mail application on iOS 10.0.1.

Comment: Is the only differences that the Terms, Privacy, and Unsubscribe links are centered? I think this answer would be more helpful if you trimmed out the irrelevant parts of the code and cropped the images, rather than expecting people to read and parse this entire behemoth.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally: on a wordpress theme with a complex CSS in which there were conflicting effects on a special class area, I just couldn't get that area centered because of the CSS conflicts. Eventually, the only way to get that part centered was to switch it from display: inline-block to display:table, and then at last it accepted the centering rules, be they text-align or margin:0 auto.

I'm not claiming my case is statistically significant, just providing personal experience feedback, in case other folks in similar distress stumble upon this page after web searches :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, display:inline-block allows elements to stack below each others without any media queries. If you set elements to display:table-cell, you can't change their layout without using a media query.