# Why is table not 100% of its parent div

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <table>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    height: 60px;
}

table {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0kxtb374/).
The problem is that `table` doesn't pick `.wrapper`'s height of `60px`. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<table>` is by default `display: table`.

Make it `display: block`.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/0kxtb374/1/)

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 60px;
}
table {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: If I lose nothing, so what's the point of having `display:table` if `display:block` would suffice?

Comment: @Maximus Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25048236/css-displayblock-vs-displaytable), might help

Answer (score 0):

You should set table width to `100%` because default table width is `auto`.

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0kxtb374/3/)

read [more](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_width.asp) about table width