# Height not being respected in absolutely positioned table

Tags: html, css

If an absolutely positioned element with `display: table` has height explicitly set, if content height is larger than provided height value, then the element will shrink wrap the content and not consider the height value.

```css
#main {
  width: 100px;
  height: 29px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 200px;
  border: 1px red dashed;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

#child {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="child">Custom Text With Validation:</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is true... So is there a question related to that fact?

Comment: Yes, the question is, why the height value is not respected. It is explicitly set and will be respected in display: block. It seems that display:table and position: absolute have some special relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the table cell that doesn't honor its parent's height for the same reason i doesn't honor `max-height`, hence pushing the table's size.

Here is 2 ways to make this to work, either set `position: absolute` on the `child`

```css
#main {
  width: 100px;
  height: 29px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 200px;
  border: 1px red dashed;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: separate;
}
#child {
  position: absolute;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="child">Custom Text With Validation:
  </div>
</div>
```

or add an extra element inside the `child` and set the `height` on that.

```css
#main {
  width: 100px;
  height: 29px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 200px;
  border: 1px red dashed;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: separate;
}
#child {
  display: table-cell;
}
#child div {
  height: 29px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="child">
    <div>Custom Text With Validation:</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

*Adding `overflow: hidden` on the table will also properly "cut" of the excess.*

Comment: Is there any spec explaining this behavior?

Comment: @whowhenhow Yes and no. If you read this, [https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-display](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-display), you'll find many _Note. Future updates of CSS may specify this further._ Since way back, table elements have weak specs. and each browser can and is interpret those somewhat different.

Comment: It seems like a bug to me since display: table means block-level element. Since height is explicitly set nobody should override it. Without using wrappers we don't have any control over the height of the positioned table.

Comment: @whowhenhow `display: table` doesn't behave as a normal block element, it behaves as a table element that has some of a block elements features. For example, a table will push an inline element to the next line, though it doesn't take full width itself, unless one set it to 100%. Would you say that that is also a bug, since a block element does take full width w/o setting it to 100%?

Comment: In the case above we still can control the width.Is ti a bug?
 Maybe as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25048236/css-displayblock-vs-displaytable

Comment: @whowhenhow No, it is not a bug. If you give a block element a width and a height, it will also overflow vertically ... https://jsfiddle.net/485vebut/ ... and this is how elements is set up to behave as their `white-space` is `normal`. Change it to `white-space: nowrap` and it will overflow horizontally ... https://jsfiddle.net/485vebut/1/ ... and so will also your _table_ sample behave ... https://jsfiddle.net/485vebut/2/

Comment: In your example, overflow vertically is expected behavior, no problem with that. the block element will not change the size, it will overflow. In the case of display: table it doesn't overflow, rather it grows. Plus the spec says: In terms of the visual formatting model, a table can behave like a block-level (for 'display: table') or inline-level (for 'display: inline-table') element.

In both cases, the table generates a principal block box called the table wrapper box that contains the table box itself and any caption boxes (in document order).

Comment: @whowhenhow Why it grows rather than overflows, W3C state: "Let _the table_ be the table represented by the table element. The _xwidth_ and _yheight_ variables give **the table's** dimensions. The table is initially empty." I interpret that as it is _the table elements_ that decide the size of the table. https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/attributes-common-to-td-and-th-elements.html

Comment: Yeah, it is in the spec. A bit misleading to call it a block level element though. Thanks.