# CSS: Overflowing HTML table

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a little table in HTML such as the following:

```css
.table {
  max-height: 160px;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.table-body {
  max-height: 100%;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.row.headers {
  background: #ddd;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.row:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #f1efef;
}

.cell {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 14px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.cell:nth-child(1) {
  width: 90px;
}

.cell:nth-child(2) {
  width: 300px;
}

.cell:nth-child(3) {
  width: 300px;
}

.cell:nth-child(4) {
  width: 75px;
}

.cell:nth-child(5) {
  width: 200px;
}

.cell:nth-child(6),
.cell:nth-child(7),
.cell:nth-child(8),
.cell:nth-child(9),
.cell:nth-child(10),
.cell:nth-child(11),
.cell:nth-child(12) {
  width: 100px;
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="headers row">
    <div class="cell">A</div>
    <div class="cell">B</div>
    <div class="cell">C</div>
    <div class="cell">D</div>
    <div class="cell">E</div>
    <div class="cell">F</div>
    <div class="cell">G</div>
    <div class="cell">H</div>
    <div class="cell">I</div>
    <div class="cell">J</div>
    <div class="cell">K</div>
    <div class="cell">L</div>
    <div class="cell">M</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
      <div class="cell">womp</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My goal is for this table to overflow in the x and y directions. However, if you scroll right, you'll see that the gray bars illuminating every other row aren't visible.

Does anyone know what I'm missing? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why are you making a table with divs?

Comment: add `display: table;` to  `.row` class...

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor that _almost_ works, but the last header doesn't fill the row--do you know why?  LawrenceCherone for mobile responsive styles

Comment: i try to resolve it .. i did not find yet... if i find then i will  leave a comment ..

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor oh lord my table has 13 columns so I needed to add `.cell:nth-child(13) { width: 100px }` to the list of 100px columns. If you make your message an answer I'll gladly accept it! If you can add an explanation why display table causes the desired behavior, that would be extra helpful!

Comment: you use two `display` property in `.cell` class

Comment: Adding `display: table;` to `.row` class and  `.cell:nth-child(13) { width: 100px }` make working correctly  for me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**add `display: table;` to `.row` class**

`display:block;` vs `display:table;`

**you can follow the question** [CSS: display:block; vs display:table;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25048236/css-displayblock-vs-displaytable#:%7E:text=Both%20will%20be%20block%2Dlevel,as%20wide%20as%20its%20contents.)

may be it will help you