# Chrome not stretching display:table elements in flex container

Tags: css, flexbox

There are a lot of questions about vertical centering, the occasional flexbox-stretching oddity, or the difference between `block` and `table` elements, but I couldn't find anything about the (unexpected) behavior of this particular combination.

I'm in a bit of a tricky situation with the markup [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/navbar) is giving me:

```css
#navbar-container {
  /* Given */
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

#navbar {
  /* Given */
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  
  /* For illustration */
  background-color: red;
}

.nav-item {
  /* Given */
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  
  /* Added to center .nav-link content vertically */
  display: table;
  
  /* Without this Chrome and Edge don't stretch to the height of #navbar(-container), but Firefox does */
  /*height: 100%;*/
}

.nav-link {
  /* Added to center content vertically */
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  
  /* Should cover #navbar's red background */
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar-container">
  <div id="navbar">
    <div id="brand">
      <!-- Gives height to #navbar -->
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
    </div>

    <div class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link">
        Item 1
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link">
        Item 2
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link">
        Item 3
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to vertically center the content of `.nav-link` across the full height of `#navbar`.
Keep in mind that I can't change **anything** about the markup here, it's given to me by the framework.

Since `#navbar` (implicitly) has `align-items: stretch`, I would assume that `.nav-item` is stretched to the height of #navbar. Firefox agrees, but Chrome and Edge don't.

The interesting part is that this happens *only* with `display: table` elements.
Any other display value (correctly) stretches `.nav-item` to the height of `#navbar`.
Note that `.nav-link` doesn't automatically stretch along in that case, but that's to be expected.

Adding `height: 100%` to `.nav-item` fixes the problem, but I can't understand *why* this is necessary.
I'm not looking for alternative vertical-centering solutions, adding the `height` works fine.
Using nested flexbox or `line-height` poses other (architectural) issues.

I suppose at this point I'm mostly curious *why* this happens, and perhaps more importantly: which browser is in the wrong here?

Comment: Your question is relative to the display differents between block and table. Does this answer your question? [CSS: display:block; vs display:table;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25048236/css-displayblock-vs-displaytable)

Comment: @MaxiGui No, I don't think so. I can't find anything in that question or its answers relating to why a `display:table` element would not be stretched in a flexbox container in some browsers.

Comment: Then here you go with [officlal doc](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-table) so table height will only grow with its content, if you dont specify a height

Comment: @MaxiGui Oooh that's interesting. So you're saying the table "wrapper" is stretched, but the the actual table itself isn't stretched to that box?

Comment: Indeed, table will not strech

Comment: @MaxiGui Interesting, so I suppose Firefox is technically in the wrong here spec-wise? Although I can understand why things behave like this, it does seem a bit "unintuitive" so to say...

Comment: I won't say that a browser is wrong over another. But I can tell you that Firefox is probably the most "precise" about CSS compare to the others. Everyday I am adapting website for firefox new updates (as it seems to be the most updates about CSS but less flexible)

Comment: @MaxiGui I guess that makes sense. If you post this information as an answer I'll gladly accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with [officlal doc](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-table).

Table elements have an internal 'table wrapper box'. This wrapper is stretched, but the actual table itself isn't stretched to that box. The table height only grows with its content, or when you specify a height.

It's unclear why, but Firefox apparently does stretch the actual table automatically.