# position relative overlapping position fixed

Tags: css, overlay, css-position

I have an position overlap problem.

I've got an menu with the following css:

```
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
top: 1em;
left: 120px;
margin-top: 0;
display: inline-table;
font-size: 0.875em;
```

And an overlay ( with some options ) with this css:

```
width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1000;
background: url('../img/overlay.png') repeat 0 0;
text-align: center;
```

As you can see is the `z-index` is set way higher then the menu. But the menu is still visible ( not grayed out ).

[Here's and saved HTM version of the site because i couldn't replicate in JSFiddle](http://weallprogram.nl/so/TTT_Server.htm)

So my question is very simple: How can I fix this? ( that the menu is "grayed out, by the background img ) just like the rest....)

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT 1**

I've updated the link. The css resources where still linked to the intern CSS. Now you should see the right site

Comment: mate..your url shows no css at all...just plain HTML!!

Comment: Does it work if you change the inline-table to an inline-block? http://stackoverflow.com/q/19352072/1540570 I'm having trouble loading you link to look at it.

Comment: According to the css you mentioned it should work and the link which you have given does not show up.

Comment: i dont think that it is possible to work with a z-index at this kind of placement

Comment: An advice: better spend some time and try to replicate everything in fiddle or other css sandbox. You might be able to find the problem yourself while doing it.

Comment: @noobEditor, i'm sorry. was still linked to the internall page here. Will fix it!

Comment: @CarolMcKay, no, that didn't work. Instead the eara only got bigger... - And I've updated the HTML, you should see the css now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your screen width, you'll have to adjust the z-indexes.Presently, you have not considered setting z-index and position in your media queries, thats why you are getting the issue..

you need to alter your media query for below case (*and others depending on your screen width*):

```
@media ( min-width:60em )
```

to

```
#menu {
    left: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position :relative; /*added*/
    z-index : -99 /*added*/
}
```

OR if you want to avoid this, define the common css at the end of the style-sheet as MQ's depend on the order (*only if they have common attribute*)

Comment: So you're basically saying that the only way to handle this problem is to let the menu disappear / hide? Because if that's the case I can just trow an `display: none;` at it right?

Comment: No, what i am saying is that depending on your screen width, you'll have to adjust the `z-index`es.Presently, you have not considered setting `z-index` and `position` in your media queries, thats why you are getting the issue IMHO! :)

Comment: if you overlay div was at the same level as the menu div (not a child div of one) it might work, that is take the div overlay out of the div container and put it between the div menu and the div container.