# Why div area still bigger more than image css?

Tags: html, css

Why div area still bigger  more than image css ?

```html
<div style="padding: 0px 0px;display: inline-table;background: red;">
            <img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/3ce23fa868ea401dac7e2fcfda5ec312.png" style="height: 70px;padding: 0;margin: 0; ">
        </div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHDU3.jpg

How can i do for set div area to fit image ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMG - is inline element, so it behaves differently than block type elements. You can override that by setting it's `display` to `block`

If you replace "`inline-table`" for "`inline-block`" for the div and set `display:block` for `img` - everything will be fine.
There is a good description in [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19352149/35954)

Comment: can i ues inline-flex ?

Comment: you surely can, but It has less support in non major browsers than inline-block.

Comment: display:block on image will solve it. flex just does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Is it fine now?

set width for image.

```css
body,html{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin: 0! important;
  padding : 0! important;
  }
img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  }
div{
  width:100%;
  height:20%;
  }
```

```html
<div style="padding: 0px 0px;display: inline-table;background: red;">
            <img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/3ce23fa868ea401dac7e2fcfda5ec312.png" style="padding: 0;margin: 0; ">
        </div>
```

Comment: I saw your div height still higher than image

Comment: @anami check now,that is the problem with your divss height and width

Answer (score 0):

Change the style in the div, this worked for me.

```
<div style="display: inline-table; width: auto; height: auto;">
    <img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/3ce23fa868ea401dac7e2fcfda5ec312.png" style="height: 70px;padding: 0;margin: 0;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set width and height of div and for inside img set 100% of width and height.

i have update the code check now
https://fiddle.jshell.net/xktb8wsL/4/

Answer (score 0):

Add to image style="display:block;"

```html
<div style="padding: 0px 0px;display: inline-table;background: red;">
    <img style="display:block;" src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/3ce23fa868ea401dac7e2fcfda5ec312.png" style="height: 70px;padding: 0;margin: 0;">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With img tag Use Css **vertical-align middle;** **width:100%;**

```html
<div style="padding: 0px 0px;display: inline-table;background: red;">
        <img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/3ce23fa868ea401dac7e2fcfda5ec312.png" style="height: 70px;padding: 0;margin:0;
vertical-align: middle; width: 100%; ">
</div>
```

```html
<div style="padding: 0px 0px;display: inline-table;background: red;">
        <img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/3ce23fa868ea401dac7e2fcfda5ec312.png" style="height: 70px;padding: 0;margin: 0;vertical-align: middle;width: 100%; ">
</div>
```